# Update depatch error while remote deployment to GAE via Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, dispatch

I'm using Google Plugin for Eclipse to deploy my app to GAE.

During "Deploy to Remote Server", console show me below error

> 95% Closing update: new version is ready to start serving. 
> 98%
>   Uploading index definitions. 
> 99% Skipping dispatch.xml - consider
>   running "appcfg.sh update_dispatch " or using the
>   "--auto_update_dispatch" option
>
> Update for module default completed successfully.

I tried run the command from GAE SDK (appcfg.cmd update...) from console, it is success.  But deployment via Eclipse still having same error.

**So alternative is to use "--auto_update_dispatch" option, may I know how can I enter that parameter in Eclipse?**

[image]

Comment: FWIW, that's just an info msg, not an error - the deployment is OK, just like your `update` SDK command. But note that you should use `update_dispatch` to update the dispatch config, not just `update` in that command. Which would be your workaround in case you can't find a way to configure the `--auto_update_dispatch` option in Eclipse (you'd update the dispatch config manually with that command - not a big deal - typically the dispatch config only changes rarely, like when you add/delete services to your app).

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the reply.

I do go to command prompt, browse to the SDK folder where Eclipse refer to and run the command: appcfg.bat update_dispatch <default module WEB-INF folder>.

That commond return success.  However when I triggered the deploy to remote server from Eclipse plugin, warning still there.

Answer (score 0):

dispatch.xml should be in the default module under WEB-INF, mvn command won't update it so you have to do it manually via [update_dispatch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/appcfg-arguments#update_dispatch)

other useful [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the reply.

I do go to command prompt, browse to the SDK folder where Eclipse refer to and run the command: appcfg.bat update_dispatch <default module WEB-INF folder>.

That command return success.  However when I triggered the deploy to remote server from Eclipse plugin, warning still there.

Comment: actually you should run it after you see the warning, but does it work?

Comment: That warning always display when I trigger deploy to remote server from Eclipse.
<br>
I tried:
<br>
[Run the update first]
- Run the SDK update command from command prompt 
- Trigger the deployment from eclipse
<br>
[Run the update after]
- Run the SDK update command from command prompt 
- Trigger the deployment from eclipse
<br>
When running SDK update command, it return success.  But every time when trigger deployment from Eclipse, same warning display.
<br>
I feel the update running on command prompt have nothing related to the deployment from Eclipse.